# Terminals not frozen, but won't execute certain commands

Tags: centos, fedora, terminal

If I open a terminal and type, lets say `ll` or `ls`, the terminal just does nothing. It isn't frozen, because I can cancel the command, but it just doesn't return the result of the command. This happens for any terminal I now open.

Certain commands work, others don't:

- htop, pwd, cd, ps -aux -- all work
- ll, ls and df -h -- don't work

I have killed all my user programs/terminals I had open and still no joy. I really don't want to restart the machine because it has other programs running under other users.

Is this a known issue/what can I do to fix it?

This is CentOS 7.4

Comment: Do you have remote file systems mounted? Certain kinds of fileserver network connection trouble look like commands hanging when accessing the unreachable mountpoint.

Comment: If it's about commands trying to access the disk, then either your disk I/O is stuck, your filesystem is b0rked, or there's just a huge load on disk I/O, making everything seem stuck. If `ps aux` works, see if you have processes marked with status `D` (uninterruptible sleep / waiting for I/O).

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/661548/linux-utilities-commands-not-working-for-particular-user

Comment: @Kamaraj checked those, doesn't seem to be them

Comment: Does `ls` always hang, or only for certain directories?  Try eg `ls /bin`, `ls /proc`.

Comment: @JigglyNaga it's only on my home directory. The problem seems to be with the way its mounted.

Comment: How is it mounted?

Comment: Why is this tagged both CentOS and Fedora?

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like your home directory is on a `NFS` share or similar, and your system is having problems accessing it. So commands like `ls` and `df` are hanging as they're not able to get information from the remote filesystem.

Make sure the `NFS` share is actually accessible and your machine has permission to mount the share.